# use two condition in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I have 3 tables (shipment, Supplier, Part).

```
create table Shipment (
    SID int,
    PID int,
    Qty int,
    );

create table Supplier (
    SID int,
    Sname nvarchar(10),
    Status int,
    );

create table Shipment (
    PID int,
    Pname nvarchar(10),
    city nvarchar(10),
    );
```

I want to make this condition as a trigger to avoid the transaction.
condition: prevent transactions over 10,000 qty by a supplier who has the status equal or bellow 30.

```
SELECT        Shipment.Qty, Supplier.Status
FROM            Shipment INNER JOIN
                         Supplier ON Shipment.SID = Supplier.SID
WHERE        (Shipment.Qty >= 10000) AND (Supplier.Status <= 30)
```

I created something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[qytcontrolcheck]
   ON  [dbo].[Shipment]
   AFTER  INSERT,UPDATE
   AS 
BEGIN
            if exists (SELECT        Shipment.Qty, Supplier.Status
                    FROM            Shipment INNER JOIN
                         Supplier ON Shipment.SID = Supplier.SID
                WHERE        (Shipment.Qty >= 10000) AND (Supplier.Status <= 30) )
                                        BEGIN
                    print'NOT ENOUGH STATUS TO REGISTER THIS TRANSACTION'
                    rollback transaction; 
                END
END
```

what am I doing wrong?
thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? I know nothing about sql-server but in a similar example from the documentation, they use RAISERROR: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 , C. Using a DML AFTER trigger to enforce a business rule between the PurchaseOrderHeader and Vendor tables

Comment: by not working I mean miss working! The SID 3 has a 30 status, which should be able to register and insert QTY over 10000 in the shipment table, but it can't. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace , inside trigger code, the table `Shipment` with `Inserted`;

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[qytcontrolcheck]
   ON  [dbo].[Shipment]
   AFTER  INSERT,UPDATE
   AS 
BEGIN
            if exists (SELECT        Shipment.Qty, Supplier.Status
                    FROM   Inserted as Shipment
                            INNER JOIN   Supplier ON Shipment.SID = Supplier.SID
                    WHERE        (Shipment.Qty >= 10000) AND (Supplier.Status <= 30) )
                                    BEGIN
                RAISERROR('NOT ENOUGH STATUS TO REGISTER THIS TRANSACTION',16,1);
                rollback transaction; 
            END
END
```

dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c6bb71f62f3e490107431646a410013c)

Comment: thank you for your answer but the issue is still there, I did what you said but I can't insert qty value for status above 30 which should be ok.

insert into Shipment(SID,PID,Qty)
values ('3','1','20000')
----------------------------------
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: yes SID 3 and 5 have a status of 30 and should be able to register QTY over 10000 in shipment, but they can't.

Comment: @masoudhanifehzadeh, maybe you need to change this `AND (Supplier.Status <= 30) ` to this `AND (Supplier.Status <30)`

Comment: Yes exactly, I change the <= to < and it worked like a charm. Thank you sooooo much